# https POST not working as expected in golang , but works fine in Python

Tags: go, post, https, jql

I am trying to implement a python code from the JIRA REST API examples:

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-jql/#api-rest-api-3-jql-parse-post

My python code (which works as expected):

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

url = "https://my-url.com/rest/api/2/search"
auth = HTTPBasicAuth("user1", "pwd1")
headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
payload = json.dumps( {
   "jql": "my-query-string"
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=auth, verify=False)
print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

I'm trying to transform this to a `golang` code as below:

```
package main
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
}
func main() {
      timeout := time.Duration(500 * time.Second)
      client := http.Client{
          Timeout: timeout,
      }
      req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://my-url.com/rest/api/2/search", nil)
      if err != nil {
          log.Fatalln(err)
      }
      req.SetBasicAuth("user1", "pwd1")
      req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      q := url.Values{}
      q.Add("jql", "my-query-string")
      req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
      fmt.Println(req.URL.String())
      resp, err := client.Do(req)
      if err != nil {
          log.Fatalln(err)
      }
      defer resp.Body.Close()
      
      data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
      if err != nil {
          log.Fatalln(err)
      }
      log.Println(string(data))
```

The code builds with no issues. When I run the `go` code, I get this error:

```
   2021/04/17 19:36:31 {"errorMessages":["No content to map to Object due to end of input"]}
```

I have 2 questions :

```
a. How can I fix the above error ?
b. I also want to include concurrency in the same code, i.e the same POST request will actually be executed for 5 different query strings (concurrently) and fetch the results, how can i achieve that ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [`POST`](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-issue-search/#api-rest-api-2-search-post) requests you need to send the data as json. Note that in Go setting a request's `Content-Type` header does *not* automagically convert whatever you give it to the specified type.

An example sending json.

```golang
package main

import  (
    "strings"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    body := strings.NewReader(`{"jql": "project = HSP"}`)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://your-domain.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search", body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req.SetBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    out, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

If you want to use query parameters you should use the endpoint with the [`GET`](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-issue-search/#api-rest-api-2-search-get) method.

```golang
package main

import  (
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    query := url.Values{"jql": {"project = HSP"}}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://your-domain.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search?" + query.Encode(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req.SetBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    out, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```